# Swipe and touch action works incorrectly

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swipe

I have a cell, with swipe actions and have a stars in this cell:

[image]

Stars is a simple UIButtons with "Touch up inside" action. When i begin swipe from empty place all work correct, but if i begin swipe from star, it show part of actions button then it clicks on star and close actions... How to prevent this ?

Comment: Do you have some code to share with us? What "action button" are you referring to?

Comment: You need to add some code @Arti

Comment: what code do you need ?

Comment: left actions i added with:

```func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use buttons, but images, and add gesture recognizers to catch taps & pans, calculate the position of the finger, and light up the corresponding star images.

Comment: any code exaple, i have no idea :( How to recognize what they want, swipe or click...